# Load images in background

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, tableview, uitableview

There is the `tableView`. It's taking the data from the array (`cellMap`). In `viewDidLoad` that data is adding to array.

```
[self.cellMap addObject:[CellModel initWithTitle:title
                                           price:price
                                           image:getProductImageByImgURL:url
];
```

In method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` the data is taken from the array:

```
CellModel *model = self.cellMap[indexPath.row];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:configurator.identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.title = model.title;
cell.price = model.price;
cell.image = model.image;

return cell;
```

Method for image load in background:

```
- (UIImage *)getProductImageByImgURL:(NSString *)url {
     __weak typeof(self)weakSelf = self;
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
         __strong typeof(self)strongSelf = weakSelf;

         strongSelf.productImage = [UIImage loadImage:url];
     });
     return self.productImage;
}
```

Where `self.productImage` is `@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *productImage;`

The result - all cells have a last loaded image. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem results from this,

```
strongSelf.productImage = [UIImage loadImage:url];
```

You can try to use a temporary variable. And make it,

```
UIImage * tempImage = [UIImage loadImage:url];
```